# Don't have privilege as admin to create permission sets

Tags: rest-api, administration, permission-sets

I'm playing around with SF's REST API, going through the tutorial. I've pulled down a valid access_token, and now I'm trying make this simple request below:

curl https://na17.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"

I get this error:
  **"message" : "API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner",
  "errorCode" : "API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG"**

I'm on a Developer Edition 30-day trial. Poking around, I read that I had to make sure the 'Enable API' permission was set for the user. I only have one user right now, the admin. I read that I had to create a permission set in order to enable the api permission. However, when I try to create a permission set, I get this error:

**Insufficient Privileges

You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.**

I don't really understand, considering the only user I have is an admin, and that's what I am logged in as while trying to create this permission set. I've been digging around for a while and am at a loss right now.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Is your org updated to winter 15 release?

Comment: Hi Mohith, couple of things. Apparently I'm on the Professional Edition, even though I signed up at developers.salesforce.com. And it appears I have Summer '14. Not sure how to sign up for the Dev Edition trial.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/en/signup?d=70130000000td6N                            Can you sign up here .So the issue is because you are on Professional Edition .

Comment: As I understand it, with the Dev Edition API access comes by default, correct? So this is the page that I originally signed up with, which is why I thought I had the Dev Edition. But when I login to SF and hover over the title, it says Professional Edition.

Comment: Thats weird ,try once more and yes thats the answer ,for professional edition you need to contact sfdc for access of API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the edition is professional edition,one needs to contact SFDC to get API access.

API access comes by default for developer,enterprise and also unlimited or performance editions .